# pandas pivot_table: MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas

is there any way how to do pivot_table on many columns (around 400)? What is the limit for this function anyway?

When I run

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index=["ID"], values=["AMOUNT"],
               columns=["MCC_CODE"], aggfunc=[np.sum])
```

on small amount of data it runs well, but when I run it on all the data I'll get `MemoryError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...tools\pivot.py", line 83, in pivot_table
    margins=margins)
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...tools\pivot.py", line 120, in pivot_table
    table = agged.unstack(to_unstack)
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\frame.py", line 3859, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level)
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\reshape.py", line 400, in unstack
    return _unstack_multiple(obj, level)
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\reshape.py", line 294, in _unstack_multiple
    unstacked = dummy.unstack('__placeholder__')
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\frame.py", line 3859, in unstack
    return unstack(self, level)
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\reshape.py", line 404, in unstack
    return _unstack_frame(obj, level)
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\reshape.py", line 445, in _unstack_frame
    return unstacker.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\reshape.py", line 147, in get_result
    values, value_mask = self.get_new_values()
  File "C:\Users\KL16166\...core\reshape.py", line 184, in get_new_values
    new_values = np.empty(result_shape, dtype=dtype)

MemoryError
```

Data look like this:

```
     ID          MCC_CODE  AMOUNT
0    24880505     9402      1
1     7276993     6011      7
2    94238163     5198      1
3    45832413     5309      2
4     6170989     6011      9
```

And I want to transfor the dataset to look like this:

```
             sum                                              ...
           AMOUNT                                             ...
MCC_CODE    4812 4816 5039 5072 5085 5122 5198 5200 5309 5411 ...  5691
ID                                                    ...
3968474      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
5803653      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
6170989      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...     1
7276993      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
22691875     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
23470633     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
24880505     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
34676389     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
35444221     NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
44226894     NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
44926723     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
45832413     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    2  NaN ...   NaN
46623281     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
48554278     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
52911146     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
69161440     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
80738635     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...     1
80966690     NaN  NaN    2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
81479745     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
83560007     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   22 ...   NaN
94238163     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
95633282       4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN
```

Info about dataset:

`>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3002680 entries, 0 to 3002679
Data columns (total 3 columns):
NR_KLIENTA    int64
MCC_KOD       int64
POCET         int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 91.6 MB`

I wonder if there is any workaround for this. Thanks

EDIT:
Now I found out that [this question was already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201754/pandas-pivot-table-alternative-for-very-large-restructure) on stackoverflow with no result. Is there any alternative in python to do the pivot with aggregation that can be used on large datasets?

EDIT EDIT:
OK I managed to solve it by changing 32bit version of Python to 64 bit version. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: That pivot can look different depending on the data... and you didn't post any data.  please read the attached links and consider editing you question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How many unique IDs and MCC CODE's do you have? More importantly, how much RAM do you have? I don't think there is any limitations on the function itself.

Comment: Ok, maybe that's the problem. I have  8 GB of RAM. And the table has 305 000 IDs and 474 MCC_CODEs. Could it because of this?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to check the limits of float32 and float16 with `np.finfo('float32')` and `np.finfo('float16')`. If the maximum/minimums look like they won't cause any problems for you, you can try `df.astype('float32')`. With float 64, the end pivot table would take about 1GB. What is the current size of your dataframe? You can check it with `df.info()`.

Comment: I tried to run  `pd.pivot_table(df.astype('float32'),index=["NR_KLIENTA"],values=["POCET"],columns=["MCC_KOD"],aggfunc=[np.sum])` but with no success